# How to make image grid view that numbers of photos per row fit to screen?

Tags: html

I want to know how to make that showing numbers of photos per row as long as they fit in screen?

For example that it only shows 2 photos per row using mobile phone in portrait orientation then when it turned into landscapes it become 3, 4 or 5 photos per row. If they use computer/laptop, the numbers of photos per row will increase as long as they fit in the screen.

[Preview when viewed on mobile phone in portrait orientation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHjpM.jpg)

[Preview when viewed on mobile phone in landscape orientation. Note that the number of photos per row still the same and the red box that will should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqJZn.jpg)

This is my code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" /><br /></td>
    <td><img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" /><br /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" /><br /></td>
    <td><img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" /><br /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" /><br /></td>
    <td><img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" /><br /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" /><br /></td>
    <td><img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" /><br /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to expect that the numbers of photos are depending on the screen size. If the screen size is small, the numbers of photos per row is small while the large will be increase.

And the result is the number of photos per row is still the same.

I think my code is wrong?

Comment: You can try using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead of tables.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this is using a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

In your case, you can do like this:

```css
#imageContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 100vw;
}
img {
  margin : 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="160" height="160" />
 </div>
```